# Vue.js how to access axios inside java script files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I imported `axios` to the `main.js` and set this

```
Vue.prototype.$http = axios;
```

For that reason now I don't need to import `axios` for each and every component.
Now I can refer `axios` in **vue components** like this

```
this.$http
      .post(`/public/api/login`)
      .then(response => {
        console.log("ddddddddd",response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("Error is", error);
      });
  }
```

But my problem is when is use it inside my `store.js` file.

> Cannot read property '$http' of undefined

Reason may be the store.js is a java script file not a vue file.
Now my question is how can I access `axios` in my `store.js` file.

Comment: store.js is probably related to vuex which is not a Vue instance.

Answer (score -1):

Import axios in main store file and set
Vuex.prototype.$http = axios

Comment: If you read my question that is what I mentioned here. This way I can't access it from java script file. that is my question.

Comment: U used Vue.prototype not Vuex.prototype